# Delete table records daily

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I am developing android app like daily collection. in this application I want delete record daily when user open his application 1st time in day, all data save into sqlite database.

Comment: post the code what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a record in DB, you should use this syntax:

```
DELETE FROM yourTable
WHERE column=value;
```

Please provide more details (DB scheme?) if you require more specific response.

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to store a column which have current date-time.
when app starts you have to check date if it is last day date you need to remove other wise leave it but if it is same day leave it.